# Android weight and layout width

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a Linear Layout and a button inside it. I want the button to fit about 90% of the layout width. Following some tutorial I used the attribute layout_weight and that's my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
   android:weightSum="5" >

<Button 
   android:id="@+id/newgame"

   android:layout_width="0dp" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_weight="4"

   android:text="@string/newgame"
   android:textSize="16sp"
   android:typeface="monospace"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:background="@drawable/backrepeat" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, my button disappear if I set the layout_width to 0dp like most of the tutorials say... What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the orientation of your LinearLayout to horizontal or add an invisible View with weight 1.

Comment: And you just want do know about orientation even though you are using weights if you use the Correct layout...orientation and values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
 >

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/newgame"
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="9"

    android:text="@string/newgame"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

By default the orientation of Linear Layout is horizontal so it will now align it considering the horizontal width. :)

Comment: Thanks! I only had to add android:weightSum="10" to LinearLayout to make it work :)

Answer (score 2):

Linear layout weight distributes space only in the dimension of the layout's orientation. You have a vertical linear layout and an element that is 0px wide - the weight mechanism won't add anything to that. Change the linear layout orientation to horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Vertical orientation!]

[image: Vertical]

You can set the Weight easily you just use like this....**Instead of 0dp you must use the 0dip**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newgame"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    android:text="@string/newgame"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="monospace" />

</LinearLayout>
```